# How can I install CKEditor on a server without downloading the files locally?

Tags: wysiwyg

A bit of background info before I get down to my question - I'm using the URL method of loading modules to Drupal as I do not wish to save them to my dinosaur age PC. I have also not uploaded Drupal to my PC, but am operating it via Pantheon. This is not only because of my old PC, but as I am only in the very early stages of developing my website, one advisor has said I don't need to worry about that and other programs such as MySQL.

I'm keen to get CKEditor onto my Drupal platform, so have added the CKEditor - WYSIWYG HTML editor module and this appears so far to be successful.

The tutorial I am following assumes that I am able to save the CKEditor program to my PC... which I guess in essence I can, but I am hoping there is a way to avoid doing this and load it the same way I do a module via URL perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Pantheon assumes that you are using git; although there is an on-server development feature, the primary workflow is designed to use git as a conduit between your local machine and Pantheon's servers.

Nearly all tutorials you encounter will also assume you are able to download files to your server/local machine.

Even if you don't install Drupal to your local machine, you can clone your Pantheon repository and download/edit/commit the files locally without running Apache, MySQL, etc.  ([Documentation here](http://helpdesk.getpantheon.com/customer/portal/articles/361247-starting-with-git))

I would not try loading modules via URL using Pantheon; you need to learn how to use Git or you will constantly be running into problems later when you try to sync your sites.

Alternately, if you just want a WSYIWYG editor and some other nice features, you could try spinning up the Panoply distribution of Drupal 7, which includes a bunch of modules pre-configured out of the box (though it still has a fair number of bugs).

Comment: Yes I've switched Pantheon from Git to SFTP to make life easier for now, but appreciate where you are coming from with your advice on needing to learn git. My main concern here is that if I start saving git files and others associated I am not familiar with how I can back up those files inexpensively or safely in case my PC crashes. If this happens and I don't have them backed up, what happens to my website? I replaced the hard drive and upgraded the ram 3 years ago, the laptop is going on 8 years old.

Comment: Everything you add in Git will be added to Pantheon when you run the command 'git push'.  So, you will always be able to re-download your files from Pantheon (using Git) if something goes wrong.  The git files on your computer will be a copy of those on the Pantheon servers.  This takes some time to learn but will definitely pay off in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for that Patrick, will take your advice on that one. You've been very helpful. Will no doubt be back on here while I'm on this next learning curve!! :)